# Replace regex unexpected result

Tags: sed

I'm trying to replace *keywords* marked by curly brackets `{}` like `{date}` or `{name}` with `%@` symbols. For this I use `{(.*?)\}` regex.

So, I wrote this test script:

```
echo "hello { welcome } and { welcome} home {friend } {(friend)}" | sed "s; {\(.*\?\)\}; %@; g"

output: hello %@
```

But I was expecting `hello %@ and %@ home %@ %@` result.

More simple replacement worked perfect:

```
echo "hello {} and {} home {} {}" | sed -e "s; {\}; %@; g"

output: hello %@ and %@ home %@ %@
```

And now I'm stuck with 0 ideas how to fix the issue.

Comment: or switch to perl: `perl -pe 's; \{(.*?)\}; %@;g'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 {\(.*\?\)\}
```

See that `.*` is greedy and so the above regex will match from the first `{` up to the last `}` in line. That justifies the output.

Also notice you are doing nothing with the capture groups `\( \)`, so they can be removed, and the last brace does not need to be escaped. So the regex could be rewritten into `{.*\?}`.

Maybe your confusion arises because you are used to Perl regexes? In Perl regex, `.*?` is non-greedy, but `sed` does not use them, it uses BRE basic regular expressions.

Now, to get the desired output, go for

```
 {[^}]*}
```

This will match each value inside the braces, as `[^}]*` means "any number of non-`}` characters".

```
$ echo "hello { welcome } and { welcome} home {friend } {(friend)}" | 
  sed "s; {[^}]*}; %@; g"
hello %@ and %@ home %@ %@
```